# Drag from one sorted list to another in rails 4

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I was wondering how could I implement a drag from one sorted list and drop to another in rails 4 just like the following video explains for php.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPiq8Cvl5k4

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should watch this episode by **Ryan Bates** about **Sortable list**, this will give you an Idea, about the Sortable, drag and drop list in rails [Sortable Drag and Drop Lists](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aBsUkJMbmE).

Comment: I'll take a look at your recommendation. Thanks!